# Flutter list build

Tags: list, flutter, dart

```
void getData() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
        String text = '${f.data}'.split(":")[0].substring(1);
        print(text);
      });
    });
}
```

that code get to console,

```
I/flutter (25628): Country
I/flutter (25628): Meals
I/flutter (25628): Drinks
```

I need these values to List array, like

```
List<String> data = {"Country", "Meals", "Drinks"};
```

and it shows in

```
Widget _text() {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(data[0]), 
      Text(data[1]), 
      Text(data[2])
    ],
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Widget> data = [];

void getData() {
Firestore.instance
    .collection(collectionName)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
    String text = '${f.data}'.split(":")[0].substring(1);
    data.add(Text(text));
  });
});
}

Widget _text() {
return Column(
  children: data,
);
}
```